# does anyone know what technology is behind office web apps

Tags: outlook-web-access, microsoft-office-2010

do you know what technology was used to build office web apps.  is it silverlight? wpf?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a small [questionnaire on the Office Web Apps](http://on10.net/blogs/sarahintampa/Microsoft-Office-Web-Applications-Your-Burning-Questions-Answered/).

1. Silverlight is not required. Using Silverlight will enhance the user experience, resulting in sharper images and improved rendering. Also, the Office Live Workspace has integrated Silverlight technology into the multi-file upload function for a better experience there, too.

   - It does not matter which operating system is used as long as you're running a supported web browser.
   - Microsoft will deliver Office Web applications to consumers through Office Live, which is a consumer service with both ad-funded and subscription offerings. That seems to imply a free (ad-supported) and paid (subscription) offering will be available.

[Microsoft begins previews of Office Web Applications](http://uk.news.yahoo.com/16/20090917/ttc-microsoft-begins-previews-of-office-6315470.html).

> The Office Web Applications are still a work in progress, and that testers will have access only to Word, Excel and PowerPoint to start with. Only Excel and PowerPoint currently offer the ability to create and edit files, and only Excel currently has support 
>   for multi-authoring, whereby two or more users can work on the same document simultaneously.

[First glimpse: Microsoft Office Web Apps](http://tech.yahoo.com/news/infoworld/20090917/tc_infoworld/92117)

> Outlook Web Access was the very first AJAX application, and it duplicated the functionality of the desktop version of Outlook admirably. Microsoft has taken much the same approach in crafting Web-based versions of Word, Excel, PowerPoint, and OneNote, but modern improvements in browser technology have made for an even more polished user experience.
>
> "Web Apps" is the official branding for the online versions of the Office suite, and the name fits. These are real, standards-based Web applications -- no Silverlight or ActiveX controls required. You don't even need Internet Explorer, but you do need a modern browser.
>   (while) Microsoft won't formally support Chrome or Opera, but reps say current versions of those browsers will probably work, too.

Comment: Arguably Silverlight or Flash applications are also "standards-based" ... aaand, in terms of performance I'd take them over AJAX most of the time :-)

Comment: Flash seems a resource hog on a lot of PCs. If you want to know how loud your fans can get, just play a youtube video in fullscreen (that is especially true on a Mac). I've seen a lot of sites that use AJAX while still keeping performance levels high.

Comment: what about the new version of Word online? This question is 11years old, but nowadays the office Word online is pretty awesome, it has almost all features of the standalone desktop version, and the UX is awesome

Answer (score 1):

Here is the word development blog.  They will tell you http://blogs.msdn.com/microsoft_office_word/